# Comportamiento inintencionado al convertirse en componente de react (efecto parallax se estanca en la esquina)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css3, tailwind

Buenas tengo el siguiente problema, realize este experimento en html basico y queria que me ayudaran a saber como convertirlo a un componente de react. Como esta en mi [repo](https://github.com/rdev32/motion-background)
Yo pienso que seria algo asi

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'

const Motion = () => {
  const containerRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
      const container = containerRef.current
      if (!container) return

      const leap = 50

      const mouse = {
        x: e.pageX - container.offsetLeft,
        y: e.pageY - container.offsetTop,
      }

      const ctx = {
        width: container.offsetWidth,
        height: container.offsetHeight,
      }

      const position = {
        x: (mouse.x / ctx.width) * leap,
        y: (mouse.y / ctx.height) * leap,
      }

      container.style.transition = 'background-position 0.5s ease'
      container.style.backgroundPosition = `${position.x}% ${position.y}%`
    }

    const container = containerRef.current
    if (!container) return

    container.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove)

    return () => {
      container.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove)
    }
  }, [containerRef])

  return (
    <div
      className="h-dvh overflow-hidden bg-[url('https://github.com/rdev32/food-menu-app/blob/main/src/assets/landing.jpg?raw=true')] bg-fixed bg-center bg-no-repeat text-gray-300"
      ref={containerRef}
    >
      <div className="h-full w-full bg-[#000000aa]">
        <article className="flex h-full w-full flex-col items-center justify-center gap-10 align-middle">
          <div className="flex w-[40em] flex-col items-center justify-center gap-8 align-middle">
            <h1 className="w-full border-8 border-dashed border-gray-300 px-12 py-8 text-center text-9xl max-sm:w-[80%] max-sm:text-6xl">
              Sample
            </h1>
            <div className="max-sm:text-md flex flex-col justify-center px-14 align-middle text-2xl max-sm:w-[80%] max-sm:px-2">
              <span
                style={{
                  fontFamily: 'Courier New',
                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                  textAlign: 'left',
                }}
              >
                {"/'xyz,/"}
              </span>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque, consequuntur!
              </p>
            </div>
            <div className="flex w-full items-center justify-between gap-12 align-middle max-sm:w-[80%] max-sm:flex-col max-sm:gap-5">
              <a className="max-sm:text-md flex-1 rounded border-4 border-gray-300 px-12 py-2 text-center text-2xl transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:border-gray-50 hover:bg-[#ffffff50] hover:text-gray-50 max-sm:w-full" href="/login">Lorem.</a>
              <a className="max-sm:text-md flex-1 rounded border-4 border-gray-300 px-12 py-2 text-center text-2xl transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:border-gray-50 hover:bg-[#ffffff50] hover:text-gray-50 max-sm:w-full" href="/register">Lorem, ipsum.</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Motion
```

El codigo parece funcionar (pero no tengo idea si estoy usando el hook correcto) porque cada vez que voy a **mover el mouse en la pantalla.. pues se va a la esquina superior izquierda** y de ahi no se mueve mucho. Si pueden ver [aqui](https://rdev32.github.io/motion-background/) pues la "camara" o como se llame deberia estar apuntando siempre al centro y no cambiarse a una esquina.

Mi codigo en html, css y js funciona muy bien pero no se como hacerlo en react podrian ayudarme a corregirlo?

Comment: Probaste cambiando el leap de 50 a 100? a mi me funciono bien asi.

Comment: hola @infinit3Loop__ es que nesesito que se mueva mas lento pero creo que `leap` malogra toda la formula